# CSS templates recommenced for business web apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

A lot of CSS templates are fixed-width, typically 9xx pixels wide...

Currently I am building an intranet Rails app and wonder is there any good source of CSS templates for business apps. Requirements are:

- good for both small (1024 x 768) and large (1920 x 1400) screens
- lots of tables in the apps, maximize the screen estate (no blank space at left or right)
- two columns, a fixed width (~160 pixel wide left column for navigation, login)
- vertically, divided by header, breadcrumb, content (2-column), footer

Basically we'd like to use the whole screen for displaying data. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look at doing the 960 fluid grid system, perfect for each of the requirements you listed: http://www.designinfluences.com/fluid960gs/

There's also an oldie (but goodie) the CSS Layout Gala: http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/ - That has pretty much any layout configuration under the sun, and you do not need to change the markup, only include different css files.

**edit**

Awh heck here's a few more:

Iron Myers: http://layouts.ironmyers.com/

Design Shack: http://designshack.co.uk/articles/free-css-layout-templates

Dynamic Drive: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/category/C13/P0/